# Architecture style and patterns diffrenet?

Tags: architecture

I am new to the Software engineering. When I try to find out two topics which are architectural patterns and architectural styles I become confused. Because some of the document in the internet explain them as a same and others explain as two topics. In the documents which are says they are two terms didn't explain clearly how they are differ.

So I need a help to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear distinction, so you don't have to be confused. Like many terms in software engineering, these are used differently by different people. What makes it worse is that many people like to use these terms without really having a clue, think Bullshit Bingo.

However there seems to be a consensus that styles are more general and thus less specific than patterns. A pattern is more like a recipe from which a software architecture or part of it can be derived.

So I would consider a layered architecture to be a style but Model-View-Controller to be a pattern. But this is only my own opinion.